# Can't make my scraper print and write results accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape some contents from a webpage. The scraper is doing good when it comes to parse the data. There are two fields to scrape `name` and `data` each of which contains lists of items. However, when I print it, the result becomes messy because I'm unable at this point to print them properly.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LINK = 'http://active.boeing.com/doingbiz/d14426/geoprocess.cfm?ProcessCode=000&pageID=m20487&Country=AllLocations&State='

def get_item(url):
    res = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
    name = [item.find_next_sibling().text for item in soup.select("strong")]
    table = soup.select('table[cellspacing="1"]')[0]
    for items in table.select("tr")[1:]:
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]

        print(name,data)  #this is where I need to twitch the code to get them printed like how it should be

        with open("itemresults.csv","a",newline="") as infile:
            writer = csv.writer(infile)
            writer.writerow(name,data)  #I can't write them like so but if I try like [name,data] this the results are messy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_item(LINK)
```

For the clarity: the list within `name` variable should be printed once but they are being printed keeping pace with lists within `data` variable.

```
As they are big enough to show how the expected result look like, I'm trying with a demo:
"1,2,3" are within "name".


I wish to get them printed like below:

1 2 3   q w e
        a s d
        c x r

They are printed like the following instead:

1 2 3   q w e
1 2 3   a s d
1 2 3   c x r
```

The bottom line is:

```
1. I wish to get them printed accordingly and
2. Write in a csv file in the right way
```

Comment: `['000', '000', 'Boeing Information Only', 'Boeing Info Only', 'Boeing Information Only']
['AUSTRIA', '', 'BE10410486', 'MAGNA STEYR']
['CHINA', '', 'BE10409781', 'FESHER AVIATION COMPONENTS ZHENJIANG CO LTD']
['CHINA', '', 'BE10050454', 'SHENYANG AIRCRAFT CORP']`

this is the kind of output you want ?

Comment: Please see the edit. Thanks.

Comment: add the fixed code see if that is what you want

Comment: Thanks @ toheedNiaz, for your answer. The thing is I like to get the content of `name` and `data` side by side not serially like I've tried to show above. Thanks.

Comment: that data will make no sense csv file. have you checked the generated csv file?

Comment: The one you suggested below I've already tried myself in the first place before creating this post. Thanks again.

Comment: please check the updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168729/discussion-between-toheedniaz-and-topto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your Question correctly,
you want name as header or title of your csv file and is should be appended only once in csv file as well as in prints.

**Issue with your code :**

you have `name` in for loop which will print name every time for loop executes same is the case of write in csv file.

**Fixed Code**

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LINK = 'http://active.boeing.com/doingbiz/d14426/geoprocess.cfm?ProcessCode=000&pageID=m20487&Country=AllLocations&State='

def get_item(url):
    res = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
    name = [item.find_next_sibling().text for item in soup.select("strong")]
    spaces = len(" ".join(itm for itm in name))*"  "
    table = soup.select('table[cellspacing="1"]')[0]
    for idx, items in enumerate(table.select("tr")[1:]):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        if idx == 0:
            print(name,data)  #this is where I need to twitch the code to get them printed like how it should be
        else:
            print(spaces,data)
        with open("itemresults.csv","a",newline="") as infile:
            writer = csv.writer(infile)
            if idx == 0 :

                writer.writerow([name,data])  #I can't write them like so but if I try like [name,data] this the results are messy
            else:
                writer.writerow([spaces,data])  #I can't write them like so but if I try like [name,data] this the results are messy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_item(LINK)
```

**Output**

```
['000', '000', 'Boeing Information Only', 'Boeing Info Only', 'Boeing Information Only'] ['AUSTRIA', '', 'BE10410486', 'MAGNA STEYR']
                                                                                                                                                 ['CHINA', '', 'BE10409781', 'FESHER AVIATION COMPONENTS ZHENJIANG CO LTD']
                                                                                                                                                 ['CHINA', '', 'BE10050454', 'SHENYANG AIRCRAFT CORP']
                                                                                                                                                 ['GERMANY', '', 'BE10364235', 'AERO COATING GMBH']
                                                                                                                                                 ['GERMANY', '', 'BE10022527', 'BFG FEINGUSS NIEDERRHEIN GMBH']
                                                                                                                                                 ['GERMANY', '', 'BE10394502', 'MT AEROSPACE AG']
                                                                                                                                                 ['GERMANY', '', 'BE10341261', 'XPERION GMBH & CO KG']
                                                                                                                                                 ['GERMANY', '', 'BE10023472', 'ZOLLERN ALUMINIUMFEINGUSS SOEST GMBH & CO KG']
                                                                                                                                                 ['INDIA', '', 'BE10387428', 'ADVANCED METALLURGICAL LAB']
                                                                                                                                                 ['MEXICO', '', 'BE10404178', 'MONTERREY AEROSPACE MEXICO']
                                                                                                                                                 ['NETHERLANDS', '', 'BE10334331', 'PM AEROTEC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'AL', 'BE10039892', 'GENERAL DYNAMICS OTS DRI INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CA', 'BE10059366', 'CANYON COMPOSITES INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CA', 'BE10031203', 'GENERAL VENEER MFG  CO']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CA', 'BE10038216', 'SAI INDUSTRIES']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CA', 'BE10277597', 'SANTIER INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CA', 'BE10053288', 'TIODIZE CO INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CA', 'BE10273067', 'VALLEY DESIGN & MFG INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'CT', 'BE10054071', 'KAMAN PRECISION PRODUCTS']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'FL', 'BE10361256', 'BAY TECH INDS INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'FL', 'BE10067537', 'TRIUMPH AEROSTRUCTURES VOUGHT AIRCRAFT DIVISION']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'FL', 'BE10278251', 'URS LABORATORIES DIVISION']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'GA', 'BE10055356', 'WARNER ROBINS AIR LOGISTICS COMPLEX']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'MD', 'BE10069970', 'ALLIANT TECHSYSTEMS OPERATIONS LLC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'MO', 'BE10030518', 'ESSEX INDUSTRIES INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'OH', 'BE10032670', 'HDI LANDING GEAR USA']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'OH', 'BE10408922', 'ORBIT NDT BEDFORD']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'TX', 'BE10034905', 'AERO COMPONENTS INC']
                                                                                                                                                 ['UNITED STATES', 'UT', 'BE10026661', 'OGDEN AIR LOGISTICS COMPLEX']
```

this code will produce the desired csv file
Hope this helps

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer. However, take a look at the solution (I've already provided) I was expecting to have.

Answer (score 0):

This is the very solution I was expecting to have:

```
import requests, csv
import itertools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LINK = 'http://active.boeing.com/doingbiz/d14426/geoprocess.cfm?ProcessCode=000&pageID=m20487&Country=AllLocations&State='

def get_item(url):
    res = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
    name = [item.find_next_sibling().text for item in soup.select("strong")]
    spaces = len(name)*" "
    table = soup.select('table[cellspacing="1"]')[0]
    for idx, items in enumerate(table.select("tr")[1:]):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        if idx == 0:
            list_of_tuples = [name,data]

        else:
            list_of_tuples = [spaces,data]

        item_name = list(itertools.chain(*list_of_tuples))
        with open("itemresults.csv","a",newline="") as infile:
            writer = csv.writer(infile)
            writer.writerow(item_name)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_item(LINK)
```

To see the results, care to run it.